# modalPresentationStyle not working in modal view in iOS5

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

I want to display a popup window in iPad using the UIView's presentModalViewController method in iOS5.

Even though I set the modalPresentationStyle to UIModalPresentationFormSheet, it only displays as full frame size.

I used the same code in iOS4 before, and it can display as a popup window. How to fix it in iOS5?

```
DetailViewController *d = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:d animated:YES];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us the code you are using please ?

Comment: Code added in the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS5, the modal view should be used as below.

```
DetailViewController *d = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:d];

navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Comment: This answer is misleading. There's no need for the extra UINavigationController layer. There's probably a bug in your code due to which DetailViewController depends on being contained in a UINavigationController, that's why @KIDdAe's suggestion made it crash.

Answer (score 3):

Have you try

```
d.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

instead of

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

Comment: It crashes. Anyway, I solved the problem by myself. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer.